# JavaScript - iterate on a table whose object can have 2 names

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have a `getRelatedContactsIds(relatedContacts)` method that iterates over a table `relatedContacts` and that returns its `contact.id`

```
getRelatedContactsIds(relatedContacts) {
  this.relatedContactsIds = new Set(relatedContacts.map((element) => {
    return element.contact.id
  }))
}
```

The problem i have is that i'm not sure that the `contact` object has that name, the`contact` object in the example above can be either `contact` or`detail` . and so `return element.contact.id` can also be`return element.detail.id` .
what is the cleanest way to handle this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there will *always* be either a `contact` or `details` just do a check for `contact`. If it's there return its `id` or return `details.id` instead.

```
getRelatedContactsIds(relatedContacts) {
  this.relatedContactsIds = new Set(relatedContacts.map((element) => {
    return element.contact ? element.contact.id : element.details.id;
  }))
}
```

Comment: there is no way to change the name of the property with a destructuring alias?
as `relatedContacts.map(({ contact: contact }) => )`

Comment: To destructure something you have to know its structure and, in your case, you don't.

Answer (score 1):

A short version:

```
getRelatedContactsIds(relatedContacts) {
  this.relatedContactsIds = new Set(
    relatedContacts.map(o => (o.contact || o.details).id)
  );
}
```

Code example:

```js
const arr = [{contact: {id: 30}}, {contact: {id: 30}},{details: {id: 20}},{contact: {id: 10}}];
const result = new Set(arr.map(o => (o.contact || o.details).id));

result.forEach(n => console.log(n));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using destructuring you could do something like this:

```
const arr = [{ contact: { id: 1 }},{ detail: { id: 2 }},{ contact: { id: 3 }}];

const ids = arr.map(({ contact: { id: id1 } = {}, detail: { id: id2 } = {} }) => id1 || id2);

console.log(ids);
```

Hope this helps.